# How can I set the window size using Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, window, document

I'm trying to set the dimensions of the window to 500 x 500, but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.resizeTo(500, 500)
})
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp   try the Tryit link

Answer (score 0):

You can resize only your own popup windows, not the main window:

> Can't resize a window/tab that hasn't been created by window.open.
>
> Can't resize a tab if the tab is in a window with more than one tab.

[source](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541)